# Category Filtering from two groups - relationships (?)

Tags: relationships, filter, categories, category-group

Does anyone know a way to create a category based naviagation which has two category groups that need to relate to each other in order to build out a basic list?

I have channel with two category groups assigned to it:

- Type
- Brand

I then have categories in said groups like so:

- Type

  - Guitar
  - Amplifier
- Brand

  - Guitar Brand 1
  - Guitar Brand 2
  - Amplifier Brand 1
  - Amplifier Brand 2

Now, I'd like to display a list of categories from the Brand category group. That of course is easy but, I'd like to filter that by each of the Type group categories as well.

For example: I'd like to display a list of Brands which, based on my above example cats, would display Guitar Brand 1 and Guitar Brand 2 as those are both guitars and have been assigned the Guitar category as well. I'm filtering Brands categories based on the Type (Guitars in this case).

Note: this is a global navigation so there isn't anything I can do with URLs.

Any ideas on an approach? Is this even possible with native EE? Any add-ons which would make this possible?

Thanks for your input and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, I think it's easier to setup your categories this way:

- guitar

  - guitar brand 1
  - guitar brand 2
- amplifier

  - amplifier brand 1
  - amplifier brand 2

This way, you can filter them by its parent categories.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see what you mean though, not sure it is possible in this case as we have a bunch of sub categories already and that's just going to confuse the client mixing brands with sub-categories of guitars for example there might be electric, bass, acoustic, acoustic-electric etc. then 100+ brands mixed in with that doesn't seem like a client friendly solution unfortunately.

Comment: @Natetronn, I'm sorry. I don't understood you. I can't see why this is confusing. Are you thinking about brands of amplifiers and guitars at the same time?

Comment: @Natetronn, are you using two channels? One for each product?

Comment: One channel two category groups assigned to it. What you are suggesting would force them to apply brand categories to another group of categories (type in this case.) This isn't very DRY and would create a bunch of extra work for the client. There are over 2 hundred types and over a 100 brands at this point, even before launch so, what you are suggesting is to duplicate brands over and over again. Lot's of brands live in lots of types. So the duplication would be quite a bit.

Comment: I see. And why not to use two different channels on the same field group?